# Windows service only working on my local machine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

I have developed a windows service which has been working fine, but when I use installutil to install it on any machine other than my own I receive an error stating "Exception Occurred while initializing the installation: Unable to load file or assembly [WindowsServiceName].exe or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported". Is there something in the build of my project that would cause this? I am unable to find any errors in the event log. It is like it cannot even find the file, but I have verified the path.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. I had to right click and unblock each DLL file in the project. Once I did that the service installed on the remote machine.